# wxPython : Adjusting the panels and sizers for different screen resolutions

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, alignment, screen-resolution

So, here I'm happy that I wrote the whole code for a awesome looking GUI using wxPython in a day but it evaporated when I found that the panels are getting out of the way leaving a lot of empty space on the sides or getting congested (you know how!) on a different screen resolution.

What I want to ask is that what all properties of a GUI should I adjust or care about if I want to see that the GUI's aspect ratio, frame alignment, panel alignments, sizer ratios etc. should remain intact or if there're any methods to do so, suggest me.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550018/arranging-the-panels-automatically-in-wxpython

Answer (score 2):

Sizers automatically adjust your application widgets for screen resolution, resize, etc. If they aren't doing this automatically, then there's probably something buggy in your code. Since I don't have your code to look at, try going over the wxPython tutorials on sizers very carefully. I found the book *wxPython In Action* very useful on this topic.