# Arranging the panels automatically in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

Level: Beginner

I am developing a GUI with wxPython on Windows OS. I have some problems with arranging the panels. I GUI looks like below image (Of course the menu bar and the title bar is omitted in the image).

[image]

I would take some time to explain how I create this GUI. First I get the screen size with the `wx.DisplaySize()`. Then I adjust my panels accordingly using `pos=()`. There are main 4 panels named panel-1 to panel-4. Each of this panels contains subpanels. The number of subpanels is not a contstant. I use a for loop to create and add subpanels to panels. The subpanels are added to a sizer and then the sizers are ultimately applied to the corresponding panels. My screen size according to `wx.DisplaySize()` is 1680x1050. Currently everything is working good.

Problems:

1. But as soon as I run my code on a machine with screen size 1366x768 the panels are not positioned correctly! How can I make my GUI to auto adjust the panel's arrangement according to the screen size change. I plan to use my GUI on a variety of screen sizes from tablets to large screen LCDs. I guess I have to create a sizer that add these panels named as panel-1 to panel4 to some main arbitrary panel? Or is there any better approach?
2. Currently I am have disabled the resize option of the frame. Because when I resize the frame (when option is enabled) the main window gets resized but the components (panels, buttons) inside the main windows don't get resized. How can I enable this feature so that when the main window is resized the components inside are also resized accordingly?

There maybe an error in my approach in creating this kind of GUI. I look forward any suggestions that can create this kind of GUI in a simplified way!
Thanks for your time.

PS: I can paste the code if required but I don't think it is important as it will just increase the post length and as I have tried to explain my problem in quite a detail. However my code is working good for the screen size 1680x1050.

Comment: Are you using BoxSizers?   If not, have a read about them here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/BoxSizerFromTheGroundUp.   You would usually not position the sub-panels with pos(), you would place them into the box sizer using the expand and proportion controls, then let the boxsizer handle the different window sizes.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Thanks, I am using Boxsizers for subpanels. My problem is related to panels not subpanels as mentioned in my post.

Comment: You should be using boxsizers for the panels too :)   One vertical box sizer containing two elements: Panel5 and a horizontal box sizer containing panels 1-4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use absolute positioning across different screen sizes. The wxPython toolkit provides sizers that will help you solve this problem. If all your widgets are within sizers, they will automatically resize appropriately. Here's one implementation that is very similar to your design:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class SubPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, number):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("red")

        label = "Sub panel-%s" % number
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label=label)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class ColorPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, number, color, sub_panels):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)

        label = "Panel-%s" % number
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label=label)

        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for i in range(sub_panels):
            p = SubPanel(self, i+1)
            v_sizer.Add(p, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND|wx.CENTER, 10)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(v_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        colors = [("green", 3),
                  ("yellow", 2),
                  ("light blue", 2),
                  ("purple", 2)]
        count = 1
        for color, subpanel in colors:
            panel = ColorPanel(self, count, color, subpanel)
            hsizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            count += 1

        orange_panel = ColorPanel(self, count, "orange", 0)
        v_sizer.Add(hsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        v_sizer.Add(orange_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(v_sizer)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Panels!", size=(600,400))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I hav added sizers to my code too. Unfortunately, this solves only a part of my problem. In my case the panel4 is of different size! I have to specify size=() while creating panels. My code is working well for 1680x1050 screen as I am using this size while creating a frame. But when screen size changes to some small screen then the subpanels don't appear in the panels! Moreover in my case upon resizing the frame the components like panels are not resizing like yours! Is it because I am creating a Frame with maximum screen size?

Comment: The frame size shouldn't matter. If you need to have one panel bigger than another, then change its proportion to be bigger when you add it to the sizer. If the panels are not resizing, then you may not have them all in a sizer.

Comment: Mike, Thanks once again for the suggestions. Now I have figured out a lot of stuff. Sizers really make our life simple. It reduced a lot of pain and also lines of code! I shall post my code in the question for others. Still lot to learn. :)